# Using Environment Variables in Shell Script in a GitHub Action

Tags: shell, github-actions

I have a project where I'm using GitHub Actions for the CI / CD. I have a shell script where I would like to inject environment variables from my Actions yml. Here is what I have so far:

```
  - name: docker-push
    env:
      USER: joesan
      SOME_GITHUB_REPO_NAME: github-repo-name
      GH_REPO: github.com/$USER/$SOME_GITHUB_REPO_NAME
    run: |
      echo "Running sbt assembly"
      echo $GITHUB_REF
      echo "Pushing tag into Docker Registry"
      sh ./scripts/tag_deployment.sh
```

In the tag_deployment.sh, I'm trying to use these variables:

```
....
....
git clone https://${GH_REPO}
cd "${SOME_GITHUB_REPO_NAME}"
....
....
```

But I see when the action is run that it does not print what was set!

```
Cloning into '$SOME_GITHUB_REPO_NAME'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/$USER/$SOME_GITHUB_REPO_NAME/': The requested URL returned error: 400
```

How can I inject these environment variables properly into my shell script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not so intuitive to understand from the GitHub documentation. I managed to fix this by moving the environment variables globally like this:

```
env:
  USER: joesan
  DEPLOYMENT_REPO_NAME: some-repo-name
```

And then use it in my some other job definition like this:

```
  - name: docker-push
    env:
      GH_REPO: github.com/${{ env.USER }}/${{ env.DEPLOYMENT_REPO_NAME }}
```

Comment: Would you mind showing how you call the `GH_REPO` variable in your shell script later on? I seem to have issues with that as I have my GH secrets available in the workflow files, but not in the shell files, but it also doesn't give me an error to refer to.

Comment: Have a look here if that helps: https://github.com/joesan/plant-simulator/tree/master/.github